# Does the event card "Build Master" force you to put the card back under the same pile as you choose to search in?

Tags: catan-card-game

I have a Dutch version of the Catan card-game so bear with me a little regarding translation to English.

My question refers to the event card that allows both players to search through a pile and put back one card from their hand. This event card is called "Bouwmeester" in Dutch, roughly translates to "Build Master" in English.

The Dutch text on this card is unclear about whether, when you choose to take a card from a pile, you need to put back your card under the **same** pile or may put it back under **any** pile.

So what is the formal ruling of this event card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the **same** pile.

As in the [English rulebook](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SOCCG_Base_Rules_0422406_loRez.pdf) (p22):

> Examine your chosen stack. You may choose any one card from that stack. You may also choose not to exchange any cards. Place your discarded card at the bottom of the stack and return it to the table face-down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm just wondering something. The original game is in German (I think), could it be that the English one is badly translated as well? :)

Comment: It's possible, but I doubt it. I've looked over the German rulebook, and whilst I don't have sufficient grasp of the language to translate it fully, it seems to me to be referring to a single stack as the subject of the exchange, as are the English rules.